Why are there no sheva brachos for geirim
Does anyone know the source that there are no sheva brachos for geirim?
What happens when a ger marries a divorcee? Are there 3 days?
Also, what is the reasoning behind it? If a ger is a “new person”, so much so that de’oraysa a brother and sister who each did geirus would be permitted to marry post geirus, why would this not be considered a first marriage?

Note the "Sheva" in "Sheva Brachos" refers to the number of blessings in the set not the number of days they are said for. Every marriage has Sheva Brachos said for some number of days.

Welcome to MiYodeya Vladimir and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I was under the interpretation that this rule (no 7 day sheva Bracha for geirim) applied to all geirim…not ones who were married before Geirus and then converted together.
My question is regarding two geirim who previously have never known each other and decide to get married. Is there 7 day she a brachos?

In general there is no difference between a Ger and a born Jew when it comes to Sheva brachot as long as this couple was not together before the giyur.
If the couple was together before the giyur some poskim will hold that there is no special Simcha in the now Jewish marriage and as such only one day of Sheva Brachot should be has, as by a second Jewsih marriage.
See this and this article.
There might also be a difference between if they had a civil marriage prior to the giyur or only lived together.

A couple who convert to Judaism and marry observe Sheva Berachot at the meal after the chupah but no more.
https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/3680
The reason is because that is not considered a new marriage which warrants 7 days.
https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6851

And why isn't it?

The question is why is it not considered a new marriage

Do you mean that the fact they lived together in a marital fashion prior to conversion means that the simcha of the 'new marriage' is somewhat diminished, because it lacks the novelty? If so, consider editing into your answer to make it clearer. As is stands, it doesn't answer the question.

Your answer does not provide a source why a couple who converts does not have a new marriage. Could you please also please answer other questions raised?

See https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6851 in addition to https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/3680 cited in my answer

You will find good source material and explanations in Shevet Halevi, Vol 4, Responsa 173
His bottom line: Since the couple was already married, the aspect of "being happy with this new marriage" is missing, and therefore there is no need for 7 (or even 3) days of Sheva Brachot.
Though he brings other opinions, which are based on the fact that they were never married by Jewish law.
However, he concludes, we do see that the original Ketubah that they agreed upon when they were not Jewish, if it existed, is used in the "remarriage". So the rule of them being "like newborns" isn't applied to the remarriage. This is an explicit Mishna in Ketuboth 9:9

גֵּר שֶׁנִּתְגַּיֵּר וְאִשְׁתּוֹ עִמּוֹ, כְּתֻבָּתָהּ קַיֶּמֶת, שֶׁעַל מְנָת כֵּן קִיְּמָהּ:‏


A convert who converted with his wife, the kethubah remains valid, since it is on this condition that he kept her as his wife.

It seems, that the rule about them being considered like newborns does not apply to monetary matters, and they still have to repay old debts and keep to any contracts they signed before converting.
Sources of this include the comment of R' Akiva Eiger to this Mishan.

לא ידעתי בלאו הכי אמאי לא קם ההתחייבות מעידן דהיה נכרי

Which loosely translated to:

I don't fully understand this, why isn't this included in the rule that they have to abide by all monetary obligations they agreed to before they converted?

The Shevet Halevi states that if they marry anybody other than their original spouses, that the regular rules of Sheva Brachot apply.

My understanding is that although it is actually a new marriage, the simcha is not like the simcha of a new marriage, more like the simcha of a second marriage, hence there being only one day.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for these first answers. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Note in particular the focus on sourcing your answers. Great to have you learn with us!
